# anyway to count how many times a closure has been ran?

Tags: javascript, closures

want to check if the closure that is being used had run more than 4 times if so return undefined.

```
const helloWorld = thrice(function () {
  return 'Hello World';
});
// helloWorld is the function returned from `thrice`
const firstCall = helloWorld();
// firstCall === "Hello World";

const secondCall = helloWorld();
// secondCall === "Hello World";

const thirdCall = helloWorld();
// thirdCall === "Hello World";

const fourthCall = helloWorld();
// fourthCall === undefined;

const fifthCall = helloWorld();
// fifthCall = undefined;
```

Comment: So what was your attempt at `thrice`?

Comment: You'll need to create a variable outside of your function, and increment it each time the function is called.

Comment: A functional approach: https://tsplay.dev/N9pz9w

Comment: `function thrice(fun) { 
  let counter = 0; 
  return function () {
    counter++;
    if(counter > 3) { return undefined; }
    return fun(); 
  };
}`